# Codeigniter Facebook SDK4

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

Trying to locate a code example for FB SDK4 & Codeigniter , I can see so many examples for SDK V2 and V3 but nothing for four.

Comment: Just wrap the base_facebook.php to your own CI library.

Comment: but there are so many libraries - should i include them all?

Comment: Oh I see that SDK4 is different, have you checked the https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4 ?You will get an idea.

Comment: yeah I have but its so different and im new to it, so I was thinking of a tutorial

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can't really help you unless we know what functionality of SDK 4 you need to use.